# Ionic v3 Native Keyboard usage issue due to update

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic Native Keyboard following a video tutorial for an Ionic v3 application and it seems to be an error due to changes in the version of native keyboard used in the tutorial and the current version  avaliable in Ionic documentation. Current version --> https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-keyboard

Old version uses an slightly different import method. So when I declared the **native keyboard** in constructure in `.ts` file and ran a console log to check it is functioning, I got an error:

**.ts file: **

```
import { NativeKeyboard } from '@ionic-native/native-keyboard/ngx';

 constructor(
    ...
    private nativeKeyboard: NativeKeyboard 
  ) {

    //Here comes the error:
    this.nativeKeyboard.onKeyboardShow().subscribe(() =>{
      console.log('keyboard openned')
    })
  }
```

**Error message:**

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the cordova plugin this ionic native is based on:

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-native-keyboard

It seems there is no `onKeyboardShow` method but I guess you can use the `onKeyboardDidShow` without losing functionality.